# NodeJS not starting applications

Tags: c#, node.js

I've tried:

```
child_proccess.spawnSync(`start cmd /k "start *PATH TO EXE*`, [], {shell: true})
```

and

```
child_proccess.spawnSync(`start *PATH TO EXE*`, [], {shell: true})
```

I've even tried making a C# program that stars the program via:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and calling it from nodejs using:

```
child_proccess.spawnSync(`start *PATH TO C# STARTER EXE*`, [], {shell: true})
```

My goal is restarting this application via nodejs, stopping it was simple, as you can tell. I can't figure out how to start it again.

EDIT:
Double clicking to open it or calling it from cmd works flawlessly, its just calling it from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Anything after `process.exit` will not be executed. I think the best idea is to use [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It will automatically restart your app after crash or process exit. You can specify `--stop-exit-codes <code>` option, which stops the app from restarting after exiting with specified code.

## Edit

> Ah sorry, probably have been more clear. I meant process.kill, which kills an external process. Then I am trying to restart that external process

I think you can still use PM2 through its JS API.

```js
const pm2 = require("pm2");

class PM2Process {
  #name;
  constructor(name, path) {
    this.#name = name;
    pm2.start({ script: path, name });
  }

  restart() {
    pm2.restart(this.#name);
  }
}
```

More info at https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/

Comment: Ah sorry, probably have been more clear. I meant process.kill, which kills an external process. Then I am trying to restart that external process

Comment: Now my answer should help.